Nginx + php-fpm "504 Gateway Time-out"
During some long operations that generate many PDF files, the CRM application goes into "504 Gateway Time-out" for ALL people that are using the CRM (remote and local people). I'm always forced to restart php7.0-fpm. Maybe there is some configuration error in the php.ini (like memory, cache or something else) that can cause this problem?

At this point of view of the question, the answers will be: Yes anything could make an timeout
